# PHP file read not working

Tags: php

On a server I have the file some.php. I try to read the contents using `file_get_content` and `fread`. Both these don't read my content.

If I try some other URL like yahoo.com, these functions are reading the contents. Why does this happen?

```
$my_conetn =  file_get_contents("http://example.com");
echo $my_conetn;
```

The above snippet is not working.

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, 20);
echo $contents;
fclose($handle);
```

Also the above snippet is not working.

How to check my server? Is there any file read operation locked or not?

edit: I am not sure, but it is only my server file that can't be read. I can read the other server links. So I contact my hosting provider, then I get back to you guys/gals.

Comment: What content you are trying to read? Is there a error message? Paste some example.

Comment: It would be **very** helpful if you post your code, otherwise we can only **guess** what the problem might be. Maybe yahoo's webservers all died...

Comment: ... and it would also be helpful to see some error messages.

Comment: Check if [allow_url_fopen](http://de.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using file functions to access remote files (paths starting with http:// and similar protocols) it only works if the php.ini setting `allow_url_fopen` is enabled.
Additionally, you have no influence on the request sent. Using CURL is suggested when dealing with remote files.

If it's a local file, ensure that you have access to the file - you can check that with `is_readable($filename)` - and that it's within your `open_basedir` restriction if one is set (usually to your document root in shared hosting environments).

Additionally, enable errors when debugging problems:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```